# I have an <a> button which triggers a csharp controller action, why doesn't the action trigger when clicking in between 2 letters?

Tags: c#, html

This is the code for the seen  button. It's triggering a csharp controller action to search for an ID and return the details page.

Though when I click between 2 letters, mainly: "CH" and "SU" it doesn't do anything. It feels like a dead pixel on a phone.

```html
<a class="GlobalFilter_a" id="GlobalFilterFaultReportID_a" href="@Url.Action("Details", "FaultManagement", 
    new
    {
        area = "FaultManagement",
        id = idReplacePlaceHolder,
        referer =""
    })" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove omis-default-color">
    @ResourceFormatter.Get("WebResources.GlobalFilterFaultReportID")
</a>
```

[image: Like 1 pixel problem between 2 letter doesn't trigger action]

I tried debugging, and have seen that when click between those 2 specific letters, the CSharp controller action is NEVER triggered (I have a breakpoint at debugging there, that's how I know), so it has to be an HTML problem.

I just don't have any IDEA what it could be or what I could try next to see what the real problem is. Does anyone maybe know what to try/what the problem could be?

Comment: A normal `a` tag does not exhibit this behavior, i just tested it and even with a big font size i can't click in between letters. Maybe its in your css code?